# testing callback return value with react-hooks-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, react-hooks-testing-library

In this example we have a simple hook called `useLog` that returns a method. How do I test that it gets returned with react-hooks-testing-library. I am trying to figure out how to write the expect.

The hooks useLog:

```
import {  useCallback } from 'react'
export const useLog = () => {
  const log = useCallback(() => console.log("hello World"), [])
  return { log }
}
```

test:

```
import { renderHook } from '@testing-library/react-hooks'
import {useLog} from "./useCounter";

const log = jest.fn()

test('should return log metod', () => {
  const { result } = renderHook(() => useLog())

  expect(result.current.log).toHaveReturnedWith(log);
})
```

what I get:

```
Matcher error: received value must be a mock function
Received has type:  function
Received has value: [Function anonymous]
```

Comment: `result.current.log` isn't a mock function, `log` is. But `log` is unrelated to the code under test, it's not clear why that would be any part of the expectation. It's not clear to me what `useLog` is actually *for*, so it's hard to say what a good test for it would look like.

Comment: useLog is just a example useHook, I am trying to understand how to test a return method from a hook that I am testing that uses useCallback. @jonrsharpe

Comment: `result.current.log` will contain the callback function that you defined inside the `useLog` hook. If you want to test that function, why not call it and assert that it's done what it should?

Comment: You always need to start from what the thing you're testing is supposed to do. Currently the test is named `should increment counter` - what counter? How does the expectation relate to that? Then the expectation itself is that the memoized callback, which isn't a test double (and shouldn't be, it's part of the thing you're testing), gets called and returns `log` (which has no connection to the code you're testing).

Answer (score -1):

You just need spyOn function, but your 'log' callback return nothing.
It is more acceptable:

```
import { renderHook, act } from '@testing-library/react-hooks';
import { useLog } from "./useCounter";

test('should return log metod', () => {
  const { result } = renderHook(() => useLog());
  const spy = jest.spyOn(result.current, 'log');
  act(() => {
    result.current.log();
  });

  expect(spy).toHaveReturnedWith(undefined);
  expect(spy).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  expect(spy).toReturnTimes(1);
});
```